# creating a "pop-up" mini page

Tags: javascript, popup, lightbox

### Issue

I'm planning on making a lightbox-like project page. I want to have it where the user clicks on an image and it brings up a div that contains a article with paragraphs, images, and whatever else I want to put in it. It will basically be a scrollable article that hovers over the original page which the user can close to see the project page again. I'd prefer to not force the user to download every article when they enter the gallery page.

### Request

Is there a way to pull a small article like this from say, an html file stored on the server? Is there a better way to approach this problem?

**-edit-** I'd prefer to not use jQuery or any other javascript library. This website will be presented to a Javascript course, so I would like it all to be normal javascript code. Besides, I'd would rather learn how jQuery does it than use use it blindly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it alright for the page to be displayed in an `iframe`, or would you like the content to be inserted and included directly in the main page?

Comment: Also, does it need to work in all browsers? Since IE does some things differently the code is messier if it needs to be supported.

Comment: @Jeremy I'd prefer to not use an iframe, but if the other options become to complex I might have to resort to it's use. I'd prefer the overflow to be handled by an `overflow: scroll` property. And as far as IE, for right now it doesn't need to support it, but if I ever needed to in the future It would be useful if you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple lightbox in pure JavaScript, loading its content from a specified URL. It doesn't handle errors gracefully and if it works in IE, it's only in newer versions.

Since it is taking the HTML of the target page and inserting it into your document directly, it might behave oddly if the URL points to a complete HTML page. It would work best if the URL only points to an HTML snippet (no `<html>` or `<body>` tags).

```
var lightboxPage = function(path) {
  // fetches content from a specified path and displays it in a lightbox

  var backdrop = document.createElement("div");
  var content = document.createElement("div");

  content.innerText = "Loading...";

  // use AJAX to load the content from the page
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open("GET", path, false);

  var handleAjaxEvent = function() {
    // this function is called multiple times during the AJAX request.
    // a state of 4 means that the request has completed.
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        content.innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
  }

  request.onreadystatechange = handleAjaxEvent;
  request.send();

  backdrop.style.position = "fixed";
  backdrop.style.top = 0;
  backdrop.style.height = "100%";
  backdrop.style.left = 0;
  backdrop.style.width = "100%";
  backdrop.style.zIndex = 500;
  backdrop.style.background = "black";
  backdrop.style.opacity = 0.8;

  content.style.position = "fixed";
  content.style.top = "10%";
  content.style.height = "80%";
  content.style.left = "10%";
  content.style.width = "80%";
  content.style.zIndex = 600;
  content.style.border = "none";
  content.style.overflow = "auto";
  content.style.background = "white";

  document.body.appendChild(backdrop);
  document.body.appendChild(content);

  var removeLightbox = function() {
    document.body.removeChild(backdrop);
    document.body.removeChild(content);
  }

  // remove the lightbox when people click on the backdrop
  backdrop.addEventListener("click", removeLightbox)
};

// example usage
lightboxPage("test.html");
```

[Mozilla's AJAX tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ajax) may be of use to you as well.

Comment: Thanks for you time ^_^ I'll start with something similar to this for now. I can switch out the iframe later. You don't have to give me the code for an iframeless version if you don't have time. Just give me a general description of how you would do it. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated it to work without AJAX. I hope this is useful to you. :)

Comment: Without `iframe`s, I meant; with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery and FancyBox. I think that would cover it. http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 0):

i like http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/